# Issue with hovering over tooltip jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Ok so let me give a little background as to what the problem is...

Our client has a homepage campaign area that has 9 unique links, which when hovered over fade out the underlying default background image with a front image associated with the hovered link at that time a tool tip is fired above that link with a gallery description and a link to the gallery. On mouse out the default image is to reappear behind the links.

The problem is that when hovering over a link and then hovering over the corresponding tooltip, the mouseout event triggers for the link. The client wants the image to stay when hovering over the tooltip as well. Here is the code I currently have:

```
$("a#building1").mouseover(function() {

    $("#main_image").fadeOut(1, function(){
      $("#main_image").load(function () { //avoiding blinking, wait until loaded
        $("#main_image").fadeIn();
        });

      $("#main_image").attr("src", "link-to-image-here");

    });
// each unique link has a class of building
$("a.building").mouseout(function() {

          $("#main_image").fadeOut(1 ,function(){
            $("#main_image").load(function () { //avoiding blinking, wait until loaded
              $("#main_image").fadeIn();    
              });
            $("#main_image").attr("src", "/images/banners/default.png");
          });      
    });
```

Here is the HTML markup

```
<a id="building1" class="building" href="#"></a>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <span class="event-title">Event title</span>
        <span class="location">Event location</span>  
        <a href="link-to-gallery" class="view-photos-btn">View Wedding Photos</a>
      </div>
```

I thought i could possibly use the .next() in the jQuery library to target the tooltip for each building however i am having trouble getting it to just keep the image on hover and replacing it with the default on mouse out. Any ideas? thanks in advance!

-Derek

Comment: why u dont use the mouseout event on the .tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd test for a mouseover on the tooltip from within the mouseout of the link, you could prevent it. But then you'd have to bind a mouseout to the tooltip, that tests if the mouse isn't over the button. So: as long as the mouse is over one of both, the background stays. As soon as you mouseout both, the background resets.

Comment: Thanks for that info would you mind maybe giving me a brief example if you wouldnt mind? I haven't used the .bind() before and would be very greatful if you could provide a quick simple example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm seeing your question just now. Do you still need a .bind() example?